# automatically insert nans without overwriting

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan, overwrite

I have a code which tells me at which positions there is  missing data. I need to put NaNs there, making MagMatrix1 longer. In the code below there are 4 missing data, so 4 Nan columns need to be added to the matrix.

```
vind=[5, 7, 10, 13];

MagMatrix=[ 99 98 97 94 95 96 93 92 91 96 95 94 98 98 ]
MagMatrixH1=[MagMatrix1(:,1:vind(1)-1),nanny,MagMatrix1(:,vind(1):vind(2)-2),nanny,MagMatrix1(:,vind(2)-1:vind(3)-3),nanny,MagMatrix1(:,vind(3)-2:vind(4)-4),nanny,MagMatrix1(:,vind(4)-3:end)];
```

Which is based on the principle explained here : https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1085-inserting-a-column-in-a-matrix-without-deleting-any-column 
Giving as output

```
MagMatrixH1=[ 99 98 97 94 NaN 95 NaN 96 93 NaN 92 91 NaN 96 95 94 98 98 ]
```

Making the NaNs be at positions  5, 7, 10, 13

This works, but what do I do if `vind` is a different length and I need to add for example 10 NaN rows? How do I automise this that I don't need to rewrite the code for MagMatrixH1 manually every time? Basically, what I am trying to do, is add NaNs to a matrix without overwriting what is already in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make a matrix of `NaN` values of the desired size, then assign the non-`NaN` values to it. You can do this using [`setdiff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) to get the indices for the non-`NaN` values:

```
N = numel(MagMatrix)+numel(vind);
MagMatrixH1 = nan([1 N]);
MagMatrixH1(setdiff(1:N, vind)) = MagMatrix;
```